# The CSS & jQuery code getting printed as plaintext on 200th iteration [php]

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I was working on a script where I had to show some query respective to domain type(Here mentioned as typeX & type Y).So I used jquery slidetoggle function & little bit of css.Things worked perfect until 200th iteration.
Till 199th iteration data is displayed properly with indentation like below:

```
Click To show  typeX data
//Some data shown via toggle

Click To show  typeY data
//Some data shown via toggle
```

But beyond that its prints all data & even jQuery,css as continuous line of text,even break tag is not working.Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#typeX201").click(function(){ $("#typeX201").slideToggle("slow"); }); }); $(document).ready(function(){ $("#typeY201").click(function(){ $("#itypeY201").slideToggle("slow"); }); }); #typeX,#typeY { background-color:#cccccc; border:solid 1px #a9a9a9; } #TypeX201,#typeY201 { display:none; }
//followed by some data
```

Below is my php code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<?php

    class Delete_bm
    {

    function __construct($site)
    {       
         //Creating DB Connection
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
           //Closing DB Connection
    }
    function display_data()
    {       

            $sql="Some SQL query;

        $res=mysql_query($sql,$this->db_cluster1);
                $i=1;
                while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
                {  ?>
                    <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#typeX<?php echo $i?>").click(function(){
                $("#typeXqry<?php echo $i?>").slideToggle("slow");
              });
            });
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#typeY<?php echo $i?>").click(function(){
              $("#typeYqry<?php echo $i?>").slideToggle("slow");
              });
            });
               </script>
            <style>
            #typeX?php echo $i?>,#typeY<?php echo $i?>
            {
            background-color:#cccccc;
                        border:solid 1px #a9a9a9;
            }
                        #typeXqry<?php echo $i?>,#typeYqry<?php echo $i?>
                        {
                         display:none;
                        }
            </style>
                   <div id="typeX<?php echo $i?>"><b>Click to show typeX Query</b></div>
                   <div id="typeXqry<?php echo $i?>">
    <?php                  $str="Some Query";
                       //typeX text to be displayed in every iteration;?>
    <div id="typeXqry<?php echo $i?>">
    <?php                  $str="Some Query";
                       //typeX text to be displayed in every iteration;?>
    $i++;
    }                    
    }
    }
    $list = new Delete_bm();
    $data = $list->display_data();
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What does the HTML look like for those divs?

Comment: Here's the screenshot of how its HTML looked between the two iteration.
http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5608/15618966729_efad47bb8f_h.jpg
I hope this will help you.
As you can see till 199th iteration it looked good & even showed qry using toggle but suddenly jquery & css gets printed as text on & after 200th iteration.

Comment: What is the HTML of the divs that you're putting on the page. You shouldn't be using javascript like this. It should be one function and can be applied to all of them. But without knowing the HTML structure, we can't help.

Comment: Here's the source code you were asking for:

Comment: <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#typeX199").click(function(){
$("#Xqry199").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#typeY199").click(function(){
$("#Yqry199").slideToggle("slow");
});
});</script>
<style>
#typeX199,#typeY199{
background-color:#cccccc;
border:solid 1px #a9a9a9;
}
#Xqry199,#Yqry199{
display:none;
}
</style><br>
<b>199:Domain name:abc.com<br><div id="typeX199"><b>Click to show typeX Query</b></div>
<div id="Xqry199">
//MySQL Queries
<br><br>
</div><div id="typeY199"><b>Click to show typeY Query</b></div><div id="Yqry199">
//MySQL Quries
</b><br>

Comment: @slapyo:&below is 200th iteration html code:

Comment: <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#typeX200").click(function(){ $("#Xqry200").slideToggle("slow"); }); }); $(document).ready(function(){ $("#typeY200").click(function(){ $("#Yqry200").slideToggle("slow"); }); });</script> <style> #typeX200,#typeY200{ background-color:#cccccc; border:solid 1px #a9a9a9; } #Xqry200,#Yqry200{ display:none; } </style><br> <b>200:Domain name:xyz.com<br><div id="typeX200"><b>Click to show typeX Query</b></div> <div id="Xqry200"> //MySQL Queries <br><br> </div><div id="typeY200"><b>Click to show typeY Query</b></div><div id="Yqry200"> //MySQL Quries </b><br>

Comment: Even I tried to debug this issue in different ways like checked source code esp between the two iterations,I hardly found any difference.On copied & saved the whole html output & ran it the browser,it showed the same erroneous result but when I just copied only those two iteration source code & ran in browser,it worked properly

Comment: In short even at source code level everything works fine until i print 200th element.

Comment: Have you checked the database to make sure there are not any extra tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave this part out of the loop. There is no need to duplicate code like this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".typeX, .typeY").click(function() {
            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

</script>
<style> .typeX, .typeY { background-color:#cccccc; border:solid 1px #a9a9a9; } .Xqry, .Yqry { display:none; } </style>
```

Your loop should output only this stuff.

```
<br><b>199:Domain name:abc.com<br>
<div id="typeX199" class="typeX"><b>Click to show typeX Query</b></div>
<div id="Xqry199" class="Xqry"> //MySQL Queries <br><br> </div>
<div id="typeY199" class="typeY"><b>Click to show typeY Query</b></div>
<div id="Yqry199" class="Yqry"> //MySQL Queries <br><br> </div>
```